# How do I classify errors specific to connection failure in ssis

Tags: sql-server

I do not want to fail my SSIS package when I have an error due to oledb sql server connection failure (resulting from server reboot, communication link failure, restoration activity etc).all other errors is let to fail the package.

How do I achieve this where I can classify this error for connection failure?

I tried to get the corresponding error code. For instance -1071636471. But this doesn't distinctly raise error for connection failure alone. This code is raised on event of any database object issue, primary key constraint etc.

Can anyone please help me

Please note, the connection failure in topic is not the host server on which package is hosted.

Comment: There is an AcquireConnection method on the ConnectionManager object. May be you can use it to test if acquiring a connection was successful or not?

Comment: Hi Perry, my package is connected to many source servers from where I get data. So in run time any of the source server is down, I don't want to fail the package. Acquire connection would help during design stage right?

Answer (score 1):

Right you would test each ConnectionManager. Add a ScriptTask with something like this.

```
object successfulConn = 
Dts.Connections["MySqlServerConnection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction)

if (successfulConn != null) {

// do something

Dts.Connections["MySqlServerConnection"].ReleaseConnection(successfulConn);

}

else {

// actions if connection could not be acquired

}
```

Comment: Thanks again Perry for your answer, this is inline with what I have thought. What I'm trying to achieve here is poll the execution if error is due to connection failure.(meanwhile I can get the server up again) and then rerun package from checkpoint. Else fail the package right away if the error is due to any other reason. Can you please suggest how can I achieve this